# JavaScript - Removing item name from box?

Tags: javascript

So I have an system. You click on product image it will add it to cart, if you click it again (to remove it) it will add it again to cart. How could I prevent it doing that?

Here is my JavaScript:

```
$(".item-card").mousedown(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("red lighten-1 white-text selected-item");
    var itemnume = $(this).find("img").attr("title");
    console.log(itemnume);
    $("#itemcart").html($("#itemcart").html() + "<div id="+itemnume+">"+itemnume+"</div>");
    calculateTotal();
});
```

SearchFuntcion

```
function searchItem(){
    $("#itemcart").each(function() {
        var itemnume = $(".item-card").find("img").attr("title"); 
        if($("#itemcart").html(itemnume)){
            $("#itemcart").html($("#itemcart").html() + "<div id="+itemnume+"></div>");
        }
    });
}
```

HTML for Parent

```
<div id="itemcart" style="float: left;height: 170px;width: 230px;left: 265px;">   
</div>
```

Comment: Write a function that searches `$("#itemcart")` for the item you're adding before you add it. If it's there, remove it.

Comment: I'm kinda bad, but I tried something.. That is super wrong :D.. Maybe you can take a look.. Edited first post

Comment: the `.html()` method on `$('#itemcart')` does not return true or false, it just returns the jQuery object for that item so that `if()` statement is generally going to be counted as true by javascript (since it's not a `false`, `null` or `undefined`. Also please give us any relevant HTML code. It's hard to answer a question about element manipulation if we don't have the elements in question.

Comment: By that you mean what? That's how it basically works. If you click card, then it creates under parent div the div with item name.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the item number has already been added to the cart, and then remove it.

```
$(".item-card").mousedown(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("red lighten-1 white-text selected-item");
    var itemnume = $(this).find("img").attr("title");
    console.log(itemnume);
    var cart_item = $("#" + itemnume);
    if (cart_item.length == 1) { // Already in cart, remove it
        cart_item.remove();
    } else { // Add it to cart
        $("#itemcart").append($("<div id="+itemnume+">"+itemnume+"</div>"));
    }
    calculateTotal();
});
```

Comment: Thank You, but I can't get it working sadly :(. Tells me that Syntax error from jQuery. This line `var cart_item = $(itemnume);` Edited my first post, so you could see piece of HTML who parent is for the items.

Comment: You're missing the `"#" +` to make it take the value of `itemnume` as an ID.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
var itemnumes=[];
    $(".item-card").mousedown(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("red lighten-1 white-text selected-item");
    var itemnume = $(this).find("img").attr("title");
    if($.inArray(itemnume, itemnumes)){
        $("#"+itemnume).remove();
        return;
    }
    itemnumes.push(itemnume);
    $("#itemcart").append($("<div id="+itemnume+">"+itemnume+"</div>"));
    calculateTotal();
});
```

Comment: Of course the premise is  the image's title cannot be empty

Comment: How that can work? It doesn't make kinda sense, but I'll try then

Comment: I'm sorry ,Write less a step,fixed~

Comment: Yeah, it adds it there, but doesn't remove because cart_item is not a function.. :D

Comment: It might work, but thing is what I've never understood is. If I do that: `<div id="+itemnume+"`, then it doesn't add all that text into the "". Only like first word will be there and other will go outside of it. What could be problem of t hat?

Comment: yeah，I neglect，fixed~

Comment: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ExampleName: Banana

Comment: by the way ,you can check it , the " ' ", " ) "  is wrong,edited~